# sql truncate/pad strings

Tags: sql, string

I need something like this,

```
SELECT CLIENT_AHCCCS_ID + CLIENT_FIRST_NAME + CLIENT_LAST_NAME + replace(convert(datetime, DATE_OF_BIRTH, 1), '/', '')
FROM  tblCLIENT
WHERE CLIENT_AHCCCS_ID IS NOT NULL AND CLIENT_AHCCCS_ID LIKE 'A%'
```

But have to make sure that

```
CLIENT_AHCCCS_ID        ( 9 character )
Member Last Name      ( 25 character )
First Name          ( 25 character )
```

I have to use spaces to pad the string. How could I achieve this?

Comment: sql server, sybase, oracle, for what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server, the SQL datatype char pads with strings, so you could always convert to that:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(char(9), CLIENT_AHCCCS_ID) +
    CONVERT(char(25), CLIENT_FIRST_NAME) +
    CONVERT(char(25), CLIENT_LAST_NAME) +
    replace...
```

Comment: You might want to add `COALESCE(fieldname, ''` to make sure that nulls get converted to the right lengths